# Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter version 1.22.6, I have already published my application and have to make minor changes in my application that is why I do not wish to upgrade flutter sdk in my application. But when I try to build my application it says:

```
Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds
```

It pops up till some time and then it displays the error:

```
unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database
database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.
```

I have tried the solutions such as closing the Xcode and building only from my VS Code editor, also tried flutter clean and then build. Can someone help me with this if I do not have to upgrade flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do anything, just wait another minute or two and then it works (for me, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've been encountering this issue quite frequently, a situation I didn't experience in the past. The sole remedy I've discovered involves a specific sequence of actions: initially, I open the project in Xcode, then proceed to clean the build folder, followed by a build within Xcode itself. Subsequently, I reopen the project in Visual Studio Code. From that point onwards, it becomes possible to run it directly from there. I find myself needing to perform this entire procedure every morning, but once done, it ensures smooth operation for the entirety of the day. :O

```
flutter doctor
              
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-HU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

open Terminal

```
top -o command
```

find "xcodebuild" command **PID**

```
kill -9 pid
```